# Select a certain Windows service using WMI objects

Tags: powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

The following PowerShell command would give me a list of all windows services:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service
```

What if I want to use this object to display one certain service only? Lets say I want to use it to display the spooler service only. I don't want to use the `Get-Service` cmdlet. Thought `Select-Object` would help me, but that only selects property names, not names of services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Service | Where-Object Name -eq 'spooler'
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Service | Select-Object * | Where-Object Name -eq 'spooler'
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found out that this will basically give same result as your second example:
`Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Service | Where-Object Name -eq 'spooler' | fl *`

Answer (score 1):

While filtering `Get-WmiObject` output with `Where-Object` will work, it will have a negative impact on performance if you run the cmdlet against remote hosts, because all output will be sent over the network before it's filtered on the local host. It's more efficient to filter directly with `Get-WmiObject`, so that only the relevant data is retrieved:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='spooler'"
```